# C++, how to provide the input filename from the command line, without hardcoding it in the program?

Tags: c++, filenames

This is the continuation of my previous question,
[In C++, how to read the contents of a text file, and put it in another text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763749/in-c-how-to-read-the-contents-of-a-text-file-and-put-it-in-another-text-file)

In that, I was able to able to open an input file `input.txt` and read it contents successfully,
but now i don't want to hardcode or give the input filename beforehand,

```
ifstream myfile ("input.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
```

but i want to give the input file name later after compiling the program and generating an executable file named `test`in the command line, as shown below

```
./test input.txt
```

Any suggestions on how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the command line arguments passed to your program in the `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { }
```

`argc` is the number of arguments passed to your program and `argv` contains pointers to C-strings holding the arguments passed to your program. So using this array you can access the arguments passed to your program.

But you have to pay attention: the program itself is always passed to the program as first argument. So argc is always at least one and `argv[0]` contains the program name.

If you want to access the `input.txt` from your post you could write:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   if (argc > 1) {
      // This will print the first argument passed to your program
      std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Also, `std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);` is a convenient way to access arguments.

Comment: And if you use `argv+1` instead of `argv` you omit the program name if you don't need it. @Dan That's really a very nice way to access the arguments...

Answer (score 3):

Just to addon to all the answers - You can use '*standard input and output*' of C/C++ like *printf()* & *scanf()*

```
$ ./a.out < input.file // input file
$ ./a.out > output.file // output file
$ ./a.out < input.file > output.file // merging above two commands.
```

For more info: [**REFER THIS**](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/)

And ofcourse, clean way is to use *argc/argv* as answered by fellow gentlemen.

Comment: Thanks, what is 'a.out' here ? is it the executable file generated after compiling, or is it something else ?

Comment: Yes, when you compile your C++ in Unix environment like 'g++ sample.cpp' will output binary executable file with default name a.out else you can specify name of your output file as 'sample_exec' like 'g++ sample.cpp -o sample_exec'. Then similarly you can run './sample_exec < file.input' as described above

Comment: Ok, thanks, i am working on windows and it is generating .exe file as the executable file

Comment: Doesn't matter, redirection also works in Windows but not sure. This link tells something like that (https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/filters.mspx?mfr=true). So, in principle you can do 'sample.exe < input.file'. Give it a shot and let me know as I never had the chance try this on windows

Answer (score 0):

That's what `argv` and `argc` are for.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    assert(argc >= 2); // Not the best way to check for usage errors!
    ifstream myfile(argv[1]);
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

argc and argv arguments to main would contain all input arguments to the program, google by argc/argv, or take a look at [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)